# Bootstrap tooltip won't work after update/refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

For some reason, my tooltip component is not working correctly. I assume it has something to do with the option attributes but not sure where I can fix it. I initialized the tooltip component by doing the following:

```
var options = {
  animation: true,
  container: "body",
  placement: "bottom",
  trigger: "hover focus",
};


const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll(
  '[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'
);
const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(
  (tooltipTriggerEl) => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, options)
);
```

And here is the HTML section:

```
return (
    <>
      <div
        className="card, StanderdizedBox rounded"
        style={{ background: "white", margin: "10px" }}
      >
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-secondary"
          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
          data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip"
          data-bs-title="Search users and chats."
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

When I make some changes, for example, delete the "options" after "tooltipTriggerEl", the tooltip will work as long as I am not refreshing the web page.

Edit: Just found out my "options" attributes are not working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue in SolidJS(similar to react).
The only solution I found is to bind a `onMouseOver` event and create a tooltip for every hover and calling `show` method on it.

```
<div class="col-3" onMouseOver={
    (e) => {
        $(e.target).tooltip({
            html: true,
            title: `Tooltip text`
        });

        $(e.target).tooltip('show');
    }
}>
    Some Text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I bond mine on an "onMouseOver" event and it worked mostly except when I mouse over on my button the second time, the tip will not disappear.

Comment: Last resort could be adding mouse leave event and calling `$(e.target).tooltip('hide);` to hide it.